# Block in Utility menu top only shows on home page

Tags: blocks

heres my site coonvalleytel.com/drupal

I made a block with 3 pictures that are links to youtube, twiter and facebook.  But they will only show when you are on the home page.  Do you guys have any ideas for getting it to show for every page?

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us about the view you have defined. What is the path, the filters, etc that have been included. The pages your view shows on are dependent upon the address or block settings you have defined for the view.

Comment: The block is called facebook.  i have this in it:                                                                 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/coonvalleytel"><img src="cvt-images/youtube.png" /></a><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/coonvalleytel"><img src="cvt-images/twitter.png" /></a><a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000497525953"><img src="cvt-images/facebook.png" /></a>

Comment: For pages i have All pages except those listed. with no pages listed.  Content types-If you select no types, there will be no type-specific limitation. With none selected.

Comment: What do you mean by views defined?  Sorry im pretty new to this yet. Thanks!

Comment: ok looks like some type of path issue, i put the folder cvt-images inside the drupal folder.  where should i put images so all drupal pages can access them?

Comment: My bad, I read this late in the evening and jumped to a conclusion that you were using Views module.